# expected identifier in css properties

Tags: css

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong here .I am getting expected identifier error in the background property.

```
$("#dialogTitleSpan",parent.document).css({
   "Background":"url(/"../Images/Test.gif/") no-repeat 4px 4px",
   "line-height":"170%",
   "padding-left":"28px !important",   
   "color":"orange",
   "padding-top":"30px"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colour coding tells all.

Firstly you have a `/` before the quote. Second you have unescaped quotes.

Try using single quotes instead.

Comment: Low hanging fruit, anyone? :)

Comment: The inner quotes shouldn't even be there in the first place. There is no point having them there.

Comment: thank you..not a css person and no intelli sense and 12 45..maybe time to sleep now :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find the parent of iframe?
if so, you need to ensure that DOM element #dialogTitleSpan is loaded.

Comment: I have that all figured out..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CSS-

```
 $("#dialogTitleSpan",parent.document).css({
            "Background":"url('../Images/Test.gif/') no-repeat 4px 4px",
            "line-height":"170%",
            "padding-left":"28px !important",   
            "color":"orange",
            "padding-top":"30px"
  });
```